# CSS Form alignment great in Chrome but off for Firefox

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

The following page http://drivenowcard.com/form.php works great on Chrome but when loaded with Firefox you'll notice that the form is off to the right quite a bit.

I'm new to CSS so what did I do wrong or what does Firefox do differently then Chrome?

HTML

```
<div id="beforeForm">
    <h2 id="customer" class="textFont">Customer Information</h2><h2 onclick="redirect('http://drivenowcard.com/privacy.php');" id="privacy">Privacy Notice</h2>
    <p hidden="" id="required">* Indicates a required Field</p>
</div>

<form id="actionForm" action="ajax/process.php" method="post">
    <!-- form contents -->
</form>
```

Note:
**This project is using Bootstrap 3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear a left float that is cascading down from:  `<h2 id="customer" class="textFont">`

This is the float in your CSS (don't change this)

```
#customer {
    float: left;
}
```

This is the CSS you need to add to your stylesheet to clear the float

```
#actionForm { 
    clear: left;
}
```